# realm flexible sync relationships

Tags: swiftui, realm, mongodb-atlas

I'm using realm flexible sync and I don't know how to solve the following problem:

My app consists of the following domain architecture:

- a **user** can have *many books*
- a **book** can have *multiple pages*
- a **page** can have *multiple paragraphs*

The models would look like this:

```
class Book: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var pages = List<Page>()
    
    @Persisted var ownerId = ""
}

class Page: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
    @Persisted var label: String
    @Persisted var paragraphs = List<Paragraph>()
}

class Paragraph: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
    @Persisted var text: String
}
```

When opening the realm, I subscribe to each of those collections and have defined a role at the atlas backend so every user is allowed to read and write documents where the **ownerId** is identical to there **userId**.

No I'm wondering how to deal with the related collections. I think it's not necessary to define the *ownerId* there as well, because they're not accessed on their own and just accessible via their parent, at least in the UI. But I think that wouldn't work considering the defined backend role because there's no **ownerId** present.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You've answered it yourself: "But I think that wouldn't work considering the defined backend role because there's no ownerId present." – If you are controlling the access by a backend role, then every collection has to have the `ownerId` field, otherwise it cannot be checked from the backend role and will not be passed to the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an alternate approach.

Looking at this at a high level, a book will only ever have one owner (at a time). I would avoid using id's and use the object itself to create the relationship. Otherwise, there technically isn't a true Realm relationship

```
class OwnerClass: Object {
   @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
   @Persistedvar owner_name = ""
}
```

and then

```
class Book: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var pages = List<Page>()
    
    @Persisted var owner: OwnerClass!
}
```

that way you can add observers and can navigate the graph without having to query id's; e.g.

```
let ownerName = someBook.owner.owner_name
```

The more important part: In the big picture a book has pages and paragraphs. Pages do not relate to any other books and paragraphs do not relate to any other pages. The pages and paragraphs are part of a single book only so they are 'embedded' in that book.

So am [EmbeddedObject](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/supported-types/#supported-persistedtypes) would be a better solution for pages and paragraphs.

```
class Book: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
   @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: UUID
   @Persisted var name: String
   @Persisted var pages = List<EmbeddedPage>()
   ...
```

That solves the problem presented in the question as the book has an owner and only that owner may 'work with' that book, its pages and its paragraphs.

Comment: Yes I understand your suggestion. Thank you very much! But I see one risk: with embedding the pages within an book document, isn‘t there any chance of running into the massive array anti pattern? I imagine that a book could have many pages and therefore many paragraphs. Would that not exceed the 16mb doc limit size very quickly?

Comment: That's an excellent point, and the answer will depend on the use case. Textual data is tiny so storing a book in 16Mb is a reasonable expectation. For example the book *Swift Programming Language 5.7*, which is 650+ pages and has as number of graphic elements, takes up 9Mb. *War and Peace*, 1500 pages, takes up about 2Mb. But, if the use case has documents going beyond that, then it may be best to break out the `Page` into their own collection. Then in the `Page` object, use LinkingObjects to link it back to the book (and books owner).

Comment: And that's the point I'm worried about the most to be honest. You're totally correct assuming storing `Page` and `Paragraph` as embedded objects. Especially the auto cascading delete would make managing data consistence so much easier. But there's another information I would like to store within a `Book`...

Comment: ... and that's how many times a `Book` got ordered. And for that I think a separate collection would scale better in the long run. But the problem is, that it's not possible to query for related `Order` objects using flexible sync, isn't it?

Comment: Flex sync can be queried just like a local Realm (as long as you have access the objects being queried), so yes, it's possible and we do it all the time. You may want to consider *not* storing how many times book has been ordered within the actual book. It would be better and more 'live' to query the `Orders` for the book in question (or add LinkingObjects from Book back to Orders). However, that goes beyond the scope of *this* question and rolls into a different question. I don't think you're going to run into a roles issue as if the user can access the book, they can also access the Pages.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Will ask in a separate question, because now I've got a different problem: after changing `Page` and `Paragraph` into being of type `EmbeddedObject` it seams like the views in SwiftUI wouldn't update automatically as they did before...